# Moving from runserver to a production server

Tags: django, linux, svn, textmate

I am quite new to programming, and all of my development has been on my local runserver using textmate and terminal. I have written a small app with a few hundred and I'd like to push it to an EC2 server. My only knowledge in terms of 'developing tools' is Django's local runserver, TextMate and Terminal.

What tools or programs should I look into learning to be able to have an effective workflow?Should I be using some sort of IDE over TextMate for this? My main concerns are being able to develop on my local runserver and then painlessly push that to my production server.

Comment: I would look into using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html).

Comment: @isbadawi: why? And how is that different than terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DVCS such as git or Mercurial will allow you to develop and test locally, and then push the changes to a remote system for staging and production.

Comment: What are you saying, set up post-receive hooks and just push? That'd be pretty swish.

Comment: Or just set up a makefile that pushes and bounces the server.

Comment: so using TextMate + Terminal + git would be sufficient for dev. tools? How difficult is it to learn git from scratch (i.e., the basics, just to be able to push files and changes to the server)?

Comment: I'd probably look at [this](https://github.com/jcf/git-tmbundle), but yeah. There's only a handful of git predicates you *need* to know (add, commit, clone, pull, push), so it shouldn't be very hard.

Answer (score 3):

As @isbadawi said, use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html). It's better than just using the terminal because you can automate things. As far as deployments go, you can simplify it down to: `fab -H your.host.com deploy`. Inside the file you write commands, a simple one might go:

1. Cause the server to download the most recent code from SCM
2. Update the database (syncdb / migrations / what have you)
3. Cause apache or whatever you're using to reload the configuration

As far as some more general tips go:

- If you're using WSGI, put it under source control
- Same goes with local settings files, have your deploy script rename them to `local_settings.py` as part of the build

If you're really going for painless, look into Django hosting services like [Gondor](http://www.gondor.io) or [Ep.io](http://www.ep.io). Those will have clients that you can just deploy to pseudo-painlessly, although you will have to change some settings on your side to match theirs better, as there are many many ways to deploy a Django app.

**Update:** Ep.io is no longer in business as a hosting service. My new go-to is [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com).

**Update 2:** I used to link `local_settings.py` in deployments, but now I'm leaning towards using the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` config variable. See [rdegge's "django-skel" settings](https://github.com/rdegges/django-skel/tree/master/project_name/settings) for a good way to do this.

Comment: Update: Heroku now does Django hosting as well, and it's pretty simple. They recommend you use gunicorn as the server package.